# Update Array of Objects Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I need your help, it is the first time I am here. I want to update a value of an array of objects, I tried with:

```
await Product.update({_id: idProducto, "existencias.inventario._id": inventario._id}, {$set: {"existencias.inventario.$.precio": inventario.precio}});
```

But I get the following error from mongo

MongoServerError: Cannot create field 'inventario' in element {existencias: [ { almacen: ObjectId('628524648074937d48681a09'),
inventario: [ { nombre: "PRIMERA", cantidad: 0, precio: 0, _id: ObjectId('6285351fa52367eaaa7f92f8') }, { nombre: "PREFERENTE", cantidad: 0, precio: 0, _id: ObjectId('6285351fa52367eaaa7f92f9') }, { nombre: "SEGUNDA", cantidad: 0, precio: 0, _id: ObjectId('6285351fa52367eaaa7f92fa') }, { nombre: "SIN REVISAR", cantidad: 0, precio: 0, _id: ObjectId('6285351fa52367eaaa7f92fb') },
{ nombre: "CALIDAD", cantidad: 0, precio: 0, _id: ObjectId('6285351fa52367eaaa7f92fc') } ], _id: ObjectId('6285351fa52367eaaa7f92f7') }, { almacen: ObjectId('628524658074937d48681a0c'), inventario: [ { nombre: "PRIMERA", cantidad: 0, precio: 0, _id: ObjectId('6285351fa52367eaaa7f92fe') } ], _id: ObjectId('6285351fa52367eaaa7f92fd') } ]}

```
{
...
"existencias" : [
                {
                        "almacen" : ObjectId("628524648074937d48681a09"),
                        "inventario" : [
                                {
                                        "nombre" : "PRIMERA",
                                        "cantidad" : 0,     <--- **this value needs to be changed**
                                        "precio" : 0,
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("6285351fa52367eaaa7f93ac")
                                },
                                {
                                        "nombre" : "PREFERENTE",
                                        "cantidad" : 0,
                                        "precio" : 0,
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("6285351fa52367eaaa7f93ad")
                                },
                                {
                                        "nombre" : "SEGUNDA",
                                        "cantidad" : 0,
                                        "precio" : 0,
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("6285351fa52367eaaa7f93ae")
                                },
                                {
                                        "nombre" : "SIN REVISAR",
                                        "cantidad" : 0,
                                        "precio" : 0,
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("6285351fa52367eaaa7f93af")
                                },
                                {
                                        "nombre" : "CALIDAD",
                                        "cantidad" : 0,
                                        "precio" : 0,
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("6285351fa52367eaaa7f93b0")
                                }
                        ],
                        "_id" : ObjectId("6285351fa52367eaaa7f93ab")
                },
                {
                        "almacen" : ObjectId("628524658074937d48681a0c"),
                        "inventario" : [
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the $[field] operator

```
const re = await Product.updateMany({_id: idProducto}, {$set: {"existencias.$[existencia].inventario.$[inv].precio": Number(inventario.precio)}}, {arrayFilters: [{ 'existencia.almacen': almacen}, { 'inv._id': inventario._id}] });
```